# epson stylus photo R285 prints but no ink level ubuntu 14.04

Tags: epson

I have recently migrated from Win XP to Ubuntu 14.04. My printer works but doesn't show ink levels. Is there an add on I can download. I like Ubuntu but not knowing which colour is empty will be a problem. Can anybody help.

Answer (score 1):

**MTINK**

With the package `mtink` you can meassure the ink levels in certain printers including Epson.

You can install `mtink` by:

```
sudo apt-get install mtink
```

Comment: sorry but I entered "sudo apt-get install mtink" it asked for a password but when I typed nothing appeared on the screen and I could not carry out command. I am very new to UBUNTU so it's no doubt something I am doing wrong.Dave

Comment: I have now entered PW. I was expecting ****** as I typed.Thanks

Comment: Printer not listed I picked other but no result. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded Turboprint from www.zedonet.com I have the trial version which does show the ink levels on my Epson Stylus Photo R285. So far no problems. I hope this May be of help to other users. I hope the program is legit but I was getting desperate to know the ink levels. It's a trial for one month and then you pay.